# Are fetchAll() and for() good choices for my code?

Tags: php, pdo

I use the following code: `fetchAll` and `for($mich=0;$mich<10;$mich++)`.

Is this the best way?

Is there a better way, either to optimize or replace this code?

```
<?php
include("cache/phpfastcache.php");
phpFastCache::setup("storage","auto");
$cache = phpFastCache();
$products = $cache->get("product_page");
if($products == null) {
    $akhbarkotah1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
    $akhbarkotah1->execute();
    $products = $akhbarkotah1->fetchAll();
    $cache->set("product_page", $products,30);
}
for($mich=0;$mich<10;$mich++){
    $text1 =$products[$mich][0];
    $time1 =$products[$mich][1];
    ?>
    <a class="lastnews">
        <div id="lastnews_title" class="YekanBlack10" style="width:585px;">
            <div><?php echo $text1; ?></div>
            <div class="YekanRed10" style="text-align:left">
                <?php echo timeTonow($time1); ?>
            </div>
            <div style="border-bottom:2px solid #7c0000;height:5px;"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Does your *actual* code have this [non-]indentation?

Comment: i indent code , its not important

Comment: it actually *is* important, if you want readable/maintainable code. Indentation plays a very important part in making code structure obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fetchAll` usually is not a problem. There are some things to optimize here in my opinion:

- Use a `foreach` loop instead of `for` loop. Your result is already limited. No need to duplicate this here. This removes the iterator counter and assignment:

  ```
  foreach ($products as $product) {
      $text1 = $product[0];
      $time1 = $product[1];
  ?>
  ```
- Using the Object fetch mode (returns objects instead of indexed arrays) makes this even more readable and saves you the name assignments:

  ```
  foreach ($products as $product) {
       // $product->text1; $product->time1;
  ?>
  ```
- Though I'd recommend to remove these. Introducing numbers in variable names usually suggests there is a second one. E.g. `time2`.
- As @mat's mug pointed out, indentation is very important. Same goes for empty lines. There are great to structure your code in logical blocks. For this example here, I'd have an empty line after setting up the cache and one after loading the products.

Comment: Thank you very much , can you help me for change to object fetch? i change $akhbarkotah1->fetchAll(); to $akhbarkotah1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); and $text1 = $product[0]; to $text =$product->text; is this true?

Comment: `fetch` returns a single entry only. You want all entries of the result-set: `fetchAll` should be used here (same argument though). This will return you an array of objects, one object for every row of the result-set. For detailed questions and howtos StackOverflow is the right place to ask :)

Comment: i ask this problem in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176016/using-the-object-fetch-mode-with-foreach